# How to use comma in regex for ending point?

Tags: java, regex

Say I had this...

```
<Beginning of Pattern> <VALUE I WANT> <,>
```

So I am using Regex to enter the beginning of the pattern, (.*) for the middle, but how is it possible to label the comma? I tried just the comma alone but to no avail.

Comment: could you explain more,i can't understand

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you are trying to match `VALUE I WANT` when it is followed by `<,>` and preceded by the literal `<Beginning of Pattern>`?

If so, you can use something like this:

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<Beginning of Pattern>\\s*<([^>]+)>\\s*<,>", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1); // VALUE I WANT
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to say that the VALUE I WANT is in the middle, and i'm using m.group to pull the (.*?) that's in the middle, and the , is on the end

Answer (score 1):

If your data was:

`something ValueIWant,`

Your regex should look like:

`something (.*?),`

Answer (score 0):

Change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`, which will stop the match at the *first* comma.

The code to extract your target is:

```
String target = input.replaceAll(".*AAAA('.*?),.*", "$1");
```

Comment: that did not work.. but I just realized something.. there is ' that is coming before the comma, how can you stop the SECOND character?

Comment: What do you mean "the second character"? Also, did you try the code above?

Comment: keep the ' end at the ,

Comment: See edit, but just put the quote in the group. If that doesn't work, best to post complete input and desired target from it. Examples are clearer than words can describe

Comment: no the letters and numbers can be any combination of letters and numbers

Comment: For example, how you can use any end character within a pattern, i'm trying to use a COMMA as the end character, so everything before that will show

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `([^,]*)` instead of `(.*)`? This will capture all characters except commas.

Comment: i want the comma to be the last character

Comment: I was only referring to your `VALUE I WANT` part, so the whole thing will be like: `<Beginning of Pattern>([^,]*),`  (Notice the additional ',' at the end.)